# How to add multiple different DataFrame using for loop?

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, google-colaboratory

I have multiple data frames and I want to add the values of the next data frame after the 3rd value of the previous data frame.

I am very new with pyhton and I am using google colab so I hope you can help me. Thank you very much. So below is an example of how I want to do it.

```
df1:

Index Column_1
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     1

df2:

Index Column_2
0     2
1     2
2     2
3     2
4     2
5     2

df3:

Index Column_3
0     3
1     3
2     3
3     3
4     3
5     3
```

I want to add values of df2 starting from index 3 of df1.
Also I want to add values of df3 starting from the index 6 of df2.
so basically the indices doubles as the dataframes are added.

so df1 + df2 + df3 should look lie this:

```
df4:

Index Column_1 Column_2 Column_3
0     1                 
1     1
2     1
3     1         3
4     1         3
5     1         3       
6               2       5
7               2       5
8               2       5
9                       3
10                      3
11                      3
```

or

```
df4

Index Column_4
0     1
1     1
2     1 
3     3
4     3
5     3
6     5
7     5
8     5
9     3
10    3
11    3
```

Is there a way to do this in a loop?

I hope you guys can help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: If "df3 starting from the index 6 of df2", I think your output is not right (index 5 of df2). And why for Index = (9, 10), Column_3 values are (5, 5)?

Comment: Oh, thank you for pointing that out. I was in rush when I wrote it. I edited it now :) Thank you for the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate strings ('not float')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68479681/concatenate-strings-not-float)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pd.merge`

```
df = df1.merge(df2.assign(Index=df2['Index']+3), how='outer') \
        .merge(df3.assign(Index=df3['Index']+6), how='outer')
df['Column_2'] += df['Column_1'].fillna(0)
df['Column_3'] += df['Column_2'].fillna(0)
```

```
>>> df
    Index  Column_1  Column_2  Column_3
0       0       1.0       NaN       NaN
1       1       1.0       NaN       NaN
2       2       1.0       NaN       NaN
3       3       1.0       3.0       NaN
4       4       1.0       3.0       NaN
5       5       1.0       3.0       NaN
6       6       NaN       2.0       5.0
7       7       NaN       2.0       5.0
8       8       NaN       2.0       5.0
9       9       NaN       NaN       3.0
10     10       NaN       NaN       3.0
11     11       NaN       NaN       3.0
```

**Update**

> Is there a way I can render the result in one column only?

```
df['Column_4'] = df.ffill(axis=1)['Column_3']
```

```
>>> df
    Index  Column_1  Column_2  Column_3  Column_4
0       0       1.0       NaN       NaN       1.0
1       1       1.0       NaN       NaN       1.0
2       2       1.0       NaN       NaN       1.0
3       3       1.0       3.0       NaN       3.0
4       4       1.0       3.0       NaN       3.0
5       5       1.0       3.0       NaN       3.0
6       6       NaN       2.0       5.0       5.0
7       7       NaN       2.0       5.0       5.0
8       8       NaN       2.0       5.0       5.0
9       9       NaN       NaN       3.0       3.0
10     10       NaN       NaN       3.0       3.0
11     11       NaN       NaN       3.0       3.0
```

Comment: By the way, is there a way I can render the result in one column only?

Comment: @KimYejun. I updated my answer, check `Column_4`.

Comment: Hello, I have an error saying "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str" can you help me fix this? Thank you very much

Comment: "df = df1.merge(df2.assign(Index=df2['Index']+3), how='outer') \
        .merge(df3.assign(Index=df3['Index']+6), how='outer')" ------ this code raised tthe error at first so I tried doing "str(3)" and "str(6)" and it worked. However, as I changed the numbers to string, the two lower codes with .fillna() also raised the same error :(

Comment: The problem is probably you column Index. change its type from str to int. Something like 'df['Index'].astype(int)'.

Comment: Oh yeah, actually in my dataframe I don't have a column index. I only have one column in every dataframe, I only put index in the example for easier visualization. Should I try making a column index?

Comment: ```df = df1.merge(df2.set_index(df2.index+3), how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True).merge(df3.set_index(df3.index+6), how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)``` if you dfX are dataframes. Else use `df1.to_frame().merge(...)` and so on.

Comment: Yes df1, df2, adnd df3 are series of DateFrames, thank you. I will try this first and let you know. Thank you for your hep :)

Comment: Wow it worked. But How will I add the values like the one you did before?

Comment: It doesn't change anything. It should work.

Comment: Wait what do you mean by that?

Comment: df = df1.merge(df2.set_index(df2.index+3), how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True).merge(df3.set_index(df3.index+6), how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)     --------    This code worked :) but how can I add the values in each columns? i'm sorry :(

Comment: Okay. Thank you :)

Comment: Did you solve your problem if there is one?

Comment: Yeah I did, but the fillna(0) did not work. So I used df[np.isnan(df)]=0 instead.

However if I use that, I have to use df = df1['column_1'] + df2['Column_2'] to add the values together.