# How to add or subtract values from multiple dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

Hello I have 3 different dataframes whose values I want to add or subtract values.

I have the following dataframes below and the code I used to add the values all together but I encountered an error. I would appreciate any help, thank you very much.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/노후교량/DZ_Middle_G/20km_hr_lane1_acc_middle_girder.csv')
df1.head()

output:

        TIME    DZ_middle_G_L1_20km
0       0.001   1.021e-003
1       0.002   1.597e-003
2       0.003   1.564e-003
3       0.004   1.031e-003
4       0.005   3.022e-004


df2 = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/노후교량/DZ_Middle_G/20km_hr_lane2_acc_middle_girder.csv')
df2.head()

output:

    TIME    DZ_middle_G_L2_20km
0   0.001   -6.168e-005
1   0.002   -9.240e-005
2   0.003   -7.781e-005
3   0.004   -1.962e-005
4   0.005    6.591e-005


df3 = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/노후교량/DZ_Middle_G/25km_hr_lane1_acc_middle_girder.csv')
df3.head()

output:

    TIME    DZ_middle_G_L1_25km
0   0.001   1.277e-003
1   0.002   1.996e-003
2   0.003   1.955e-003
3   0.004   1.288e-003
4   0.005   3.777e-004
```

I used this code to add the values in the dataframes:
This code is suppose to add the values of df2 to df1 starting from TIME = 3
and also add the values of df3 to df2 starting from TIME = 6.

```
df = df1.merge(df2.assign(TIME=df2['TIME']+3), how='outer') \
    .merge(df3.assign(TIME=df3['TIME']+6), how='outer')
df['DZ_middle_G_L2_20km'] += df['DZ_middle_G_L1_20km'].fillna(0)
df['DZ_middle_G_L1_25km'] += df['DZ_middle_G_L2_20km'].fillna(0)
```

However I got this Error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str
```

Here is an example of how I want the result will be:

Final DataFrame:

```
TIME df1              df2              df3
0    1.021e-003
1    1.597e-003
2    1.564e-003
3    1.031e-003       -6.168e-005
4    3.022e-004       -9.240e-005
5                     -7.781e-005
6                     -1.962e-00       1.277e-003
7                      6.591e-005      1.996e-003
8                                      1.955e-003
9                                      1.288e-003
10                                     3.777e-004
```

looks like this but the values are added together or subtracted.
I did not change the values here but the values should be added or subtracted to each other as they are combined.

Comment: Can you explain how is the final output dataframe formed?

Comment: So I wanted to add  the values together in the datafranes, but I want to add next column (df2) values starting from the 4th value of the previous column (df1). Same goes to df3. I want to add the values of df3 starting from the 4th value of df2. I hope I explained it right. 

 I did not change the values in my example though, but what i wanted is something like that. in which df1 + df2 = df2 and df2 +df3 = df3. And as I have mentioned before, I wanted df2 to start adding or subtracting values from the 4th value of df1. and df3 starts to add or subtract values from the 4th value of df2. –

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate strings ('not float')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68479681/concatenate-strings-not-float)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are updating the `Time` columns in `df.assign` before it could merge and hence it creates a whole new column.

```
df2['Time'] += 0.4
df3['Time'] += 0.8
df = df1.merge(df2, on='Time', how='outer')
df = df.merge(df3, on='Time', how='outer')
df['Time2'] = df['Time'] + 1
df['Time3'] = df['Time'] + 2
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
df['result'] = df['col1'] + df['col2'] + df['col3']
df.head()
```

I thought you will get it so I just posted the smaller version. We just increase the time to the point it matches the required row value from where we want to start.
If it solves your problem then give the green tick.

Comment: Instead of providing only solutions, it's better to explain how your solution works.

Comment: But this one only merges the two dataframe and not really doing anything with the values

Comment: @Abhishek I tried your solution but I git this error. TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: @KimYejun at which line?

Comment: @Abhishek at 'Time2'

Comment: But the values here are not added. say for example if df1 has 1 and df2 has 2, I want their values to be added together. So df1+df2 should be equal to 3.

Comment: @KimYejun Then you `Time` column is getting interpreted as `str`. Try to change it its type to float.

Comment: @KimYejun ohk. Now that I see the explanation in the comment I will try to change my answer.

Comment: The result is different :( The final result looks like the example I have shown above :(

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted? Ok, the final edit in the answer. Pretty sure this is it.

Comment: Sorry but why is there Time2 and Time3?